# how to write javascripts for the fields added using nested_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to add nested fields in a form. I am facing some problems with its design and javascript.

Here is the view

```
<%= nested_form_for @invoice,url: invoices_path,method: :post do |f| %>
<div class="row form-inline">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <ul id="sortable" class="append-table">
                <li class="table-responsive has-dropdown invoice-append">
                <div class="table items">
                    <div class="table-head">
                        <div class="th"></div>
                        <div class="th">#</div>
                        <div class="th">Name</div>
                        <div class="th">Description</div>
                        <div class="th">Quantity</div>
                        <div class="th">Item Price</div>
                        <div class="th">Total Price</div>
                        <div class="th">Taxable</div>
                        <div class="th"></div>
                        <div class="th"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-body ui-sortable">
                      <%= f.fields_for :invoice_line_items do |ff| %>
                    <div class="tr item">
                      <input type="hidden" class="invoice-item-id">
                      <input type="hidden" class="invoice-item-template-id" id="invoice_item_template_id">
                      <input type="hidden" class="invoice-item-display-order" id="invoice_item_display_order">
                        <div class="td handle-cell">
                           <div class="handle ui-sortable-handle"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="td display-order-cell">
                          <div>
                            <div class="display-order">1</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="td">
                            <div class="form-group name-container">
                                <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead name prevent-enter tt-hint" maxlength="200" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                  <input type="text" name="item0[name]" id="name" value="A" placeholder="Name" class="form-control typeahead name prevent-enter tt-input" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" dir="auto"><pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: azo-sans-web, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;"></pre><span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;"><div class="tt-dataset-invoiceItemTemplatesAutocomplete"></div></span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="td">
                            <div class="form-group description-container">
                                <textarea name="item0[description]" id="description" placeholder="Description" class="form-control description" maxlength="1000" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 60px;"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="td quantity-cell">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="item0[quantity]" id="quantity" value="5" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control quantity prevent-enter" size="5" maxlength="10">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="td original-price-cell">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">₹</div>
                                <input type="text" name="item0[original_price]" id="original_price" value="6.00" placeholder="Item Price" class="form-control original-price money-only prevent-enter" size="9" maxlength="9">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="td price-cell">
                            <label class="price-display">₹30.00</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="item0[price]" id="price" value="30.00" placeholder="Price" class="form-control price money-only" size="9" maxlength="9">
                        </div>

                        <div class="td is-taxable-cell">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember">
                                <label class="optional" for="remember"></label>
                              </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="td remove-cell">
                        </div>

                        <div class="td save-invoice-item-template-cell">
                            <a href="#" class="js-save-as-invoice-item-template">Save to Use Again</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

I am able to add nested fields, but it is not added in: `<div class="table-body">`.

The other problem i am facing is i am not able to alert the value of quantity on the focusout event of the textbox of quantity. This is what i have tried:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quantity").focusout(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Thanks for including your code. Can you please expand on what you mean by "it's not added in"?  what do you observe? what did you expect to see instead? What have you tried doing to resolve this issue? how did that work/fail for you? Also - it looks like you have *two* questions here... you should ask one question at a time so we can rite answers separately

Comment: Id of elements on HTML page must be unique, you need to change that id. You can try `$(''#quantity).on('focusout', function() { alert($(this).val()) })`.

Comment: Hi @Kien Thanh thanx for your answer. I have tried this too, but it was not working. BTW now have got the answer. The problem was the field that was being added with the help of nested_form gem so i have to use the javascript of that gem.